# Generate variable type and initializer from macro

Tags: rust, macros, declaration

I would like to generate a variable type and initializer from a (procedural) macro. Since macros consume and generate *streams* (and not *trees*) of tokens, morally, it should be possible to do something like:

```
extern crate quote;
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn foo(tokens: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    TokenStream::from(quote! {
        : u8 = 42
    })
}
```

```
pub static FOO foo!();
```

But alas, this fails with

```
   |
28 | pub static FOO foo!();
   |                ^^^ expected one of `:`, `;`, or `=`
```

Now, of course I could turn this inside out and require writing something like

```
foo!(FOO)
```

which would expand to

```
pub static FOO: u8 = 42;
```

but the reason I would like to do things piecewise is to be able to use the same macro to generate types-and-initializers in different contexts (e.g. for local `let` bindings, not just `static`s).

Comment: Well, I don’t think you need a procedural macro and imho it’d be better to just move your `static`, `let`, etc. into macro invocation (`foo!(static FOO`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do, not because `: u8 = 42` is not correctly converted to a `TokenStream`, but simply because macro *invocations* (independently of their definition) cannot occur anywhere. In particular, they can only occur where a handle of the TokenStream would be reduced to a node, which is not the case in your example. This is because Rust has to parse the file once, before it knows anything about what macros do, exactly to find out all macros. In this first step, it only knows about its own syntax. It is smart enough to say "ok, this whole node of my AST is just this macro invocation" without knowing what the macro invocation will actually do, but it can't say "this macro invocation will feed me these tokens, so the next token I should read is `;`" (which would be the case in your example), because it doesn't know what the macro does yet!

To convince yourself, image that the macro `foo!()` produces the token `mod A {`, and `bar!()` the token `}`. Then, the following example auto-destroys itself

```rust
foo!()

#[proc_macro]
fn foo(_: TokenStream) -> TokenStream { ... }
#[proc_macro]
fn bar(_: TokenStream) -> TokenStream { ... }

bar!()
```

Because if you expand correctly the macros, then they hide themselves by putting themselves into a module, which prevents the macros from being expanded, which makes them visible again, ... Even worse examples (where the issue occurs before visibility checks, at the parsing step) are easy to provide as soon as you allow what you are trying to do.